# How to calculate a value using previous rows' values in Talend

Tags: etl, talend

I have a dataset like below.

Dataset:

[image: Dataset]

Now the business logic is to find out the last paid date for each of the loans. I tried using a tmap component, it calls a java routine that has a static variable last_paid_dt which would store the transaction date when the daily deposit > 0. However, when the daily deposit is less than 0 the static var would not get changed. This works fine when the amount paid is 0.

Issue - See the red highlighted values in the table below

When the amount paid is reversed a day or after, the last paid should be from previous non-reversed positive amount. I was not able to get that done.
Also when a new loan id starts processing I need the static variable to get reset which is not currently happening.
 If my current methodology is wrong, please help me doing in a better and efficient way. Thanks

Expected output:

[image: Expected output]

Comment: I was not able to create a nice table so added an image but it's not showing up in the question inline. Kindly click on the links and it will show the datasets. Appreciate anyone's help on this question. Thanks.

Comment: first of all you need to use a Map component, with the key being the loanId
second you, should NOT overwrite the value. I.e. If the key exists in your map, then do not overwrite the value.
You can use the globalMap if you want, in that case I'd do:
globalMap.get("loan_"+loanId) != null ? globalMap.put("loand_"+loanId,loanDate) : loanDate

Comment: @Balazs - I did use a tmap component and I was able to get the below dataset. But when an amount is reversed, it doesn't go back further to find the previous positive amount.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you. What is your business logic? My solution goes for the FIRST date it finds for that loanId. Which would be the same as doing an aggregateRow group by loanId min(date) and join it in the tMap

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use a Map component, with the key being the loanId.
You don't want to overwrite the value. I.e. If the key exists in your map, then do not overwrite it with a new value. 
You can use the globalMap if you want, in that case I'd do:

> globalMap.get("loan_"+loanId) != null ?
>   globalMap.put("loand_"+loanId,loanDate) : loanDate

then later:

> globalMap.get("loan_"+loanId)

Not elegant, but works. a More elegant would be to define your own map that you put into globalMap and after the process null it out, so you free up the memory. But this all depends on the complexity of your job.

Comment: The logic is to find the last paid date so that we can find out when did the merchant paid us last. This date is to calculate and put that merchant in different buckets like early warning, not performing account etc. The problem is when they pay and two days later the payment didn't go through. If you see my dataset, the last payment was done on 7/13/2017 but it was reversed, in that case it has to look for a positive payment before that which is 7/10/2017. Does it make sense?